# Range of the command cut in unix

Tags: shell-script, cut

I'm trying to make a shell script, I want to cut a string using the 'cut' unix command, as follows:

```
namecmpaux=$(echo $namecmp |cut -c0-19)
```

But when I run the shell tells me the following error:

```
cut: fields and positions are numbered from 1 
Try `cut - help 'for more information.
```

I remember previously used the 'cut' command using zero as the lower limit position, but now tells me that the command should start at 1. Why?, depends on the operating system? previously used SunOS and now i'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything about field 0 in the cut man page on a solaris 8 system, but 0 works as the start of a range. The man page for GNU cut (i.e. linux) is quite clear that fields start with 1. Looks like you were relying on undocumented behaviour on SunOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's the same in every `cut` implementation. Numbers start at one, it's just the Solaris' one will not complain if you provide 0 and will treat it as 1. Both `0` and `1` there means the first character, and `2` means the second character:

```
$ echo test | cut -c 0-2
te
$ echo test | cut -c 1-2
te
```

`busybox` `cut` or the `cut` builtin in `ksh93` also don't complain. GNU `cut` just tries to be helpful in telling you that you probably don't have the right idea about what's the first index.

A real difference though is that GNU and busybox `cut` (at least as of 2014-03-27), count in bytes for `-c`, while Solaris or ksh `cut` count in characters (as POSIX requires).

```
$ echo 'Stéphane' | cut -c 1-4
Sté
$ echo 'Stéphane' | busybox cut -c 1-4
Sté
$ echo 'Stéphane' | ksh -c 'command /opt/ast/bin/cut -c 1-4'
Stép
```

(in a UTF-8 locale, é (U+00E9) takes 2 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that might indeed be OS-dependent (or rather dependent on who wrote your version of `cut`).

If you take a look at `man cut`, you will see that `cut` from GNU's `coreutils` counts bytes, characters and fields from 1:

> Use one, and only one of -b, -c or -f. [...] Each range is one of:
>         **N**      **N**'th byte, character or field, counted from 1

Again, this might differ on a different system if its maintainers have decided to use an implementation of `cut` other than the GNU one, so better be safe and take a look at the manpage to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

It even worked before on Linux. I was just bitten by it (On Debian, after an update to the coreutils package which contains the cut command) and found this bug.

It's a bug in coreutils:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/211262

Someone broke the backward compatibility on purpose and nobody fixed it. It used to be like that 0 was okay, too and treated as 1. Now 0 produces an error. So all scripts which depend on this behaviour are broken and must be changed.